# ngIf executing too early

Tags: angularjs

I want to show one of two sections in a single view.

```
<div ng-if="countApps() > 0">
  //stuff to show
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-if="countApps() == 0">
  //stuff to show
</div>
```

On page load, the controller will retrieve the apps and populate the `$scope.apps` variable. I have a function in the controller called `$scope.countApps` that will return the length of $scope.apps.

The problem is that the "0 apps" part of the view will appear while the results are still being fetched and then it will remove this and replace it with other part of the view if 1 or more apps is found.

How can I make it so that only the correct view is shown? I'm aware of `resolve` but I don't want to block the whole view, only the ng-if parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a function that returns the count, just bind to the count.  So on controller initialization have the countApps set to a non-value (undefined) and then whatever sets the apps, would also set the countApps to the correct value. ng-if would resolve false in both cases on initial load.  The rest of the page would load, and those sections would catch up when they finished.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ngRoute` look into the `resolve` option on the [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)'s `when` method.

That will allow you to update the scope when the asynchronous process is complete. So initially you would hide the view, then on resolve switch a flag to show everything.

Scott Allen has a nice post on it [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx).

John Papa also has a slightly different post [here](http://www.johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/).

Comment: I would like the view to be shown but with a loader. I don't want to hide the view completely as this wouldn't be a good user experience. P.S. I'm using ui-router

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't used `ui-router`, so I don't know how to handle async data loading with that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at resolve on the route side, meaning before you load the html, it will load data from the service, it can be a http service or something else.

```
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
      templateUrl: "app.html",
      controller: "AppCtrl"
      resolve: {
        apps: function (appsService) {
          return appsService.fetchApps();
        }
      }
    }
```

Then in your controller,

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'apps', function($scope, apps) {
            $scope.apps = apps;
        }
    ]);
```

Now, the html will wait for the items to be resolved before it shows it. Meaning before the controller and view loads, it will get the apps data from the appsService service.

Comment: Sorry updated question - I want the rest of the template to show straight away and this approach will block the whole page loading. Only the ngIf parts should wait.